# SQlite order by two dates in php

Tags: php, sqlite

in sqlite I have a table `files` with two columns that have the following data in them:

- **mod_date** (as Unix-Timestamp) (date when the file was created/modified, according to `filemtime`)
- **exif_datetime** (Unix-Timestamp) (date when the file was created, according to the exif data in the file)

Now I'd like to output all rows, sorted by both values. If **exif_datetime** does not exist, it should use **mod_date**, so that in the end I have a list that uses exif_datetime and mod_date (if exif_datetime is NULL) to sort. In other words, I'd like to sort by mod_date, but if exif_datetime exists, it should override the mod_date value.

I tried multiple queries but none worked the way I intended it:

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY mod_date DESC) ORDER BY exif_datetime DESC` gives me all the files where exif_datetime is NULL at the top, which is kind of intended I think.

`SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY IFNULL(exif_datetime, mod_date) DESC` gives me kind of the same result, which I don't really understand.

How can I achieve this?

Edit: Some example data:

```
         mod_date    |  exif_datetime
file1    1585908566     1365505889
file2    1585564090     NULL
file3    1585908760     1585850649
```

Expected outcome:

```
file3
file2
file1
```

Wrong outcome:

```
file3
file1
file2
```

With IFNULL in the statement it orders it in

All Files with exif_datetime, correctly ordered

All Files with mod_date, correctly ordered

Which is not what I want.

Comment: IFNULL(exif_datetime, mod_date) DESC should work. If not post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: hey @forpas I updated my post with sample data and expected results.

Comment: An easy solution would be to create a new row, check via PHP if exif_datetime exists, and insert the relevant timestamp accordingly. I just thought there would be a better way with SQL...

Comment: Can you explain why `file2` should be ordered before `file1`?

Comment: Because the exif_datetime of file1 is lower (the file is older) than the mod_date of file 2. I want to order it by mod_date, except when there is a exif_datetime, then this should "overrule" the mod_date regarding the ordering.

Comment: Then what is the problem with NULLIF()? It returns your expected output: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uCg3oWffheBQ5je6EgAE8n/0